# Doppler frequency formula (for HB100)

Tags: arduino, radar

I have a question about the formula provided on the application notes of the HB100 sensor. It is:
$$f_d = 2v \frac{f_t}c\cos(\vartheta)$$
where \$f_d\$ is the doppler frequency, \$v\$ the velocity of the object, \$c\$ the speed of light and \$\vartheta\$ is an angle formed between the intersection of the object axis and the axis of the observer (see image below).

The application note says

> if the target is moving straight toward or away from HB100 the formula is simplified to \$f_d = 19.49v\$ (\$v\$ in km/h).

I can't derive this formula, in this condition theta angle is zero, so \$\cos(0) = 1\$ and the formula I derived is about:

$$f_d = 70.17v$$

Could someone explain how the formula reported in the application note is derived?
[image]

The application note can be found [here](https://www.limpkin.fr/public/HB100/HB100_Microwave_Sensor_Application_Note.pdf)

Comment: it might help to actually link to that application note.

Comment: http://www.rfwireless-world.com/calculators/doppler-frequency-calculator.html

Comment: yes you're right, I uploaded the post with the link.

Comment: What's Ft? ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without even trying to actually do the same calculation as you: there's a *peculiar* factor of 3.6 between your result and the application note.

Chances are, either one of you or the app note author forgot to convert km/h to m/s.

(1 km/h = 1000 m / (3600s) = 1/3.6 m/s)

Comment: Marcus is exactly right! You forgot to divide by 3.6 to convert from km/h to m/s. The formula for \$f_d\$ assumes that \$v\$ is in the same (standard SI) units as \$c\$, i.e., m/s.